# Slow dispatch multiple actions Redux React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am experiencing significant slow down in my app when I am dispatching multiple actions.

Questions:

1. How does it take ~ 300 ms for each dispatch? Does this include time it takes to run action, reducer and mapDispatchToProps and other? It doesn't seem I am triggering any extra renders.
2. Why is it waiting for each dispatch to complete even though I am using redux-thunk? Isn't that the point of thunk that they would be run simultaneously?
3. I have a fairly large amount of data in my Store, could that play an effect?
4. Is 300ms a normal time that it takes to dispatch?

my components componentDidMount.

```
  componentDidMount () {
    let start = Date.now();
    let timePassed;


    this.props.action1();
    timePassed = Date.now() - start;
    console.log(timePassed); // 313 ms

    this.props.action2();
    timePassed = Date.now() - start;
    console.log(timePassed); // 652 ms

    this.props.action3();
    timePassed = Date.now() - start;
    console.log(timePassed); // 1038 ms

    this.props.action4();
    timePassed = Date.now() - start;
    console.log(timePassed); // 1441 ms


    this.props.action5();
    timePassed = Date.now() - start;
    console.log(timePassed); // 1832 ms
  }
```

My action:

```
export const action1 = () => ({
  type: 'TYPE',
  name: 'NAME',
});
```

My reducer:

```
const actionReducer = (state, action) => {
  const { name } = action;

  return setIn(state, [name], {}); // Mutable lodash version of set.
};
```

EDIT: I tried a production build and the time dropped to 0 - 2 ms per dispatch, but still I would like it to be faster in dev.

Comment: are you using redux-logger?